# Hibernate hbm2ddl create-drop

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate 3.6.x with spring and jpa persistence unit. Is there anyway to run a sql script before the schema creation ?

I need to run a some simple sql statement to create database, schema and activate postgis. Otherwise the creation of table will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> simple sql statement to create database, schema and activate postgis

You will have to create the database and at least one user "manually". Hibernate can't do everything.

You could run some SQL using `@PostConstuct` annotation and a jdbc connection, but you'll still first need a DB and appropriate user to be able to connect.

(I don't know what postgis is)

Comment: That was my tought too, just woundered if there was any built in stuff that could do this. :)